CPLEX Tuning parameter solution not providing same speed up in regular solve
I am using CPLEX Tuning tool in python for my solve. When I run the tuning tool it gives out parameters which are best for my solve:
CPXPARAM_Simplex_DGradient                       5
CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck                          1
and solve time after tuning is around ~100 secs
But when I run the solve with same parameters but without tuning tool solve time is around ~ 600 secs which is weird as these are same parameter tuning tool suggested and used to solve the problem.
I do notice that solver log is not showing presolve logs in normal solve though its there in tuning solve. I have tried specifying presolve parameter but of no help.
Any suggestion why there could be a discrepancies in both solves?
I am solving lexicographic LP problem which is having 4 levels and CPLEX tuning run on each level and provide the optimal parameters and solution

Please describe your workflow more accurately and also process the documentation (e.g. CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck has inconsistent default-behaviour when mixing language toolchains; should not be the source, but implies noise!). Imho: There is no guarantee, that timeof(tuned_on_instance_x(x)) < timeof(untuned(x)) due to the topic of performance variability in mixed-integer programming (google it) and it's implications: tuning tool will try different seeds/reorderings/solution-paths even on the same instance. Your slow-down is unexpected, but not completely impossible. Usually: tune on n>1!

Just to be clear, the tuning tool returned a proven optimal solution in ~100 seconds? Also, this is an LP, not an IP/MIP?

I am solving LP problem. My problem have lexicographic objective at 4 levels. So when I run CPLEX tuning it tunes all 4 levels and gives parameters for 4 different levels.
@prubin to answer your question its a LP problem and tool returned optimal solution in ~100 seconds

Cross-posted to the IBM Decision Optimization forum.
